# Missing wireless tools (wpa-supplicant) in fresh NixOS install

Tags: networking, wifi, wpa-supplicant, nixos

Following the [NixOS Manual](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#sec-booting-from-usb), I i) made a live USB drive, and ii) installed NixOS on my system.

Now I'm trying to set up my wireless network, and ["Wireless Networks" instructions](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#sec-wireless) aren't working for my install. What did I need to do during the install, or after install, to get this working?

Specifically, I don't have `wpa_supplicant.service`.

```
systemctl restart wpa_supplicant.service
Failed to restart wpa_supplicant.service: Unit wpa_supplicant.service not found.
```

When I just try to run `systemctl restart NetworkingService`, I get a similar error.

```
systemctl restart NetworkingService
Failed to restart NetworkingService: Unit NetworkingService not found.
```

I should mention that I configured `networking.wireless.enable = true` (in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`). In my case, rerunning `nixos-rebuild switch` doesn't work because it can't download packages from the internet.

```
$ nixos-rebuild switch
building Nix...
building the system configuration...
warning: unable to download 'https://cache.nixos.org/nix-cache-info': Couldn't resolve host name (6); retrying in 348 ms
warning: unable to download 'https://cache.nixos.org/nix-cache-info': Couldn't resolve host name (6); retrying in 619 ms
...
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/...-wpa_supplicant.service.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/...-nixos-system-
```

So it looks like I have a chicken and egg problem. I don't have networking, that would allow me to setup networking. I would have imagined that that wpa supplicant package would have been included in the base installation.

Clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: Which one of the ISO's did you use?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa It was NixOS 18.03, downloaded from the [download page](https://nixos.org/nixos/download.html). And it was the Graphical live CD, 64-bit Intel/AMD.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, solved this one.

In `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`, the setting `networking.wireless.enable = true` needed to be enabled at initial installation.

So I went back into the install USB, set that (in the mounted `/mnt/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`), and reran `nixos-install`.

From there, i) I rebooted into my updated system, based on the [Wireless Networks](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#sec-wireless) section of the manual, ii) I generated a wireless configuration with `wpa_passphrase <ssid> [passphrase] > /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`. Then iii) restarted the service with `systemctl restart wpa_supplicant.service`. Et voila!

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out! As you use NixOS you'll notice that it's very much an all-hands-on-deck open-source project. There is a small leadership team, but generally speaking it's a flexible, fluid project which adapts to the needs of its participants. I hereby invite you to not only use NixOS but also to contribute to the project as you see fit. For example, what you encountered is a defect in the installation documentation, thus I hope you'll consider contributing your findings to the NixOS installation documentation :) If I recall it's written in DocBook (XML).

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Thanks for the invite. I definitely like the philosophy and tech behind Nix/OS. I'll contribute where I can!

Answer (score 0):

My WiFi service of nixos 19.09 failed.  I tried this, and it worked.

1. Edit `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` like this.

   `networking.wireless.enable = false;
    ##Only one daemon, wireless or networkmanager, could be enabled at the same time.
    networking.networkmanager.enable = true;`
2. rebuild nixos.

   `sudo nixos-rebuild switch --upgrade --show-trace`
3. reboot and start networkmanager service daemon.

   `sudo systemctl restart networkmanager`
4. enter wifi passwork with nmcli or nmtui

   `sudo nmcli`

   or

   `sudo nmtui`

That is it.